# Call php variable in xml

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

I want make some chart using xml file and call the chart using javascript, however I got a problem in Data.php(that contain php and xml to build the chart). This is my code :

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/edb.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($db, $edb) or die(mysql_error());

$parlimen[] = "Segamat";
$parlimen[] = "Sekijang";
$parlimen[] = "Labis";


foreach ($parlimen as $p){
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ahli WHERE parlimen = '".$p."' AND status='Perwakilan'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($count) or die(mysql_error());
    //print $result['COUNT(*)'];
    //the result some thing like 
    //for three loop 100,
    //if I print like this :
    //print $p." = ".$result100['COUNT(*)']."<br/>" or die(mysql_error()) ;
    //the result will be like this
    // Segamat = 1
    // Sekijang = 0
    // Labis = 0
    }
?>
```

This is my PHP Code who contains my XML Code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<chart caption='Weekly Sales Summary for two Products' xAxisName='Weeks' yAxisName='Amount' yAxisMinValue='0' yAxisMaxValue='500' adjustDiv='0' numDivLines='9'> ";
echo "<categories>";
echo "<category Label=\"Segamat\"/>";
echo "<category Label=\"Sekijang\"/>";
echo "<category Label=\"Labis\"/>";
echo "</categories>";
echo "<dataset seriesName=\"Product A\">";
echo "<set  value='$result' /> ";
echo "<set  value='$result' /> ";
echo "<set  value='$result' /> ";
echo "</dataset>";
echo "</chart>";  
?>
```

I make these two code with the same file name Data.php, I make xml in php. I have problem to submit result from the query into xml

This is my javascript to call the Data.php and chart

```
<body>     
<div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>          
<script type="text/javascript"><!--         

  var myChart = new FusionCharts( "MSColumn3D.swf", 
  "myChartId", "400", "300", "0" );
  myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.php");

  myChart.render("chartContainer");

// -->     
</script>
```

Comment: `numberPrefix='$'` in your XML code - you'll need to escape that `$` with a `\` otherwise PHP will try and interpret it as a variable. It might also help you to look up heredoc syntax for this, would be much easier for you.

Comment: @scrowler - u means like this echo "<set  value=".$result." /> "; ?

Comment: No, the `numberPrefix='$'` is at the end of the line where you define your `chart` tag, line two or your XML example.

Comment: @scrowler - i just delete `numberPrefix='$'` and the chart is come out with empty data..tq

Comment: do not delete anything, you need to **escape** the `$` sign with a `/`

Comment: yes, how can i pass the `$result` to xml?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<chart caption='Bilangan Ahli Mengikut Parlimen' xAxisName='Parlimen' yAxisName='Jumlah(Orang)' yAxisMinValue='0' yAxisMaxValue='500' adjustDiv='0' numDivLines='9' canvasbgcolor='#FFFFFF' canvasbasecolor='#CCCCCC' showcanvasbg='1' palettecolors='#008ee4,#6baa01,#f8bd19,#e44a00,#33bdda' divlinecolor='#CCCCCC' divlinealpha='70' useroundedges='1'> ";

foreach ($parlimen as $p){
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ahli WHERE parlimen = '".$p."' AND status='Perwakilan'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($count) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<set label=\"".$p."\" value=\"".$result['COUNT(*)']."\" />";
}
echo "</chart>";
```